# Finding equation of the circle passing through intersection of given circles and one other point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, circles

> Find the equation of the circle passing through the intersection of the circles $x^2+y^2-8x-2y+7=0$ and $x^2+y^2-4x+10y+8=0$ and through $(-1,-2)$.

To start out, how can I find their intersection points? It might help, but I can't do it.

Comment: Finding the points of intersection can eventually give the answer you want but is the longest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2+y^2-8x-2y+7=0\text{ ...(1)}$$
$$x^2+y^2-4x+10y+8=0\text{ ...(2)}$$
$(1)-(2)$ we have, $-4x-12y-1=0$.
So $$y=\frac{4x+1}{-12}$$
Substitute $y=\frac{4x+1}{-12}$ into $(1)$ or $(2)$ to have a quadratic equation of $x$.